# How to find which last line executed in wordpress?

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, comments, comment-form

I got one of the sourcecode that having an issue with woocommerce comment.

After wordpress comment it displays

```
Array
(
    [rating] => 1
    [comment] => Something happen
    [_mc4wp_subscribe_wp-comment-form] => 0
    [submit] => Submit
    [comment_post_ID] => 5766
    [comment_parent] => 0
    [_wp_unfiltered_html_comment] => 6cad68cfe4
    [tk_ai] => woo:fQT1Kp63vjn1m3908bWKKL+e
    [wp-settings-1] => libraryContent=browse&editor=tinymce&align=right&urlbutton=none
    [wp-settings-time-1] => 1579699523
    [wordpress_cf_adm_use_adm] => 1
    [woocommerce_cart_hash] => 2a099b85c27ff9faf670aeec97ec3700
    [wp_woocommerce_session_d414f731f41a558e7be1db06ea7e16cf] => 1||1579872362||1579868762||0e8353ac6d791caa28508ee018d9cd50
    [scroll] => null
    [wmc_current_currency] => GBP
    [wmc_current_currency_old] => GBP
)
```

and nothing else. I have found for print_r() word in the whole project and pre_comment hook but not found where this print_r used.

I want to get the last line where the die/exit has been executed.
or method to find that where this print_r() comes from.

Comment: `grep -lri 'print_r' wp-content`?

Comment: Have you tried to turn on debugging in your wp-config? (search this site)

Comment: @kaiser yes,  I have turned on debugging. But because of spam attack it also turned off. I have cleaned spam   affected code but there are not any errors are displaing because nothing error in code. It only issue with print_r. I think if I get flow of code what is calling one by one . Its easy to find which file/function is executing.